# Cumulative distribution, integration boundaries and range for Y

Tags: probability

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0CIT.png)

Sorry for the interuption, I am quite confusing about how to seperate the function into pieces. And how to determine the boundaries for integration.

Question:
Given X follows exponential distribution with mean 1, Y follows uniform distribution over 0 to 1.

Let Z = X + 2Y, derive the CDF of Z.
Is there a general way to solve this sort of questions?

Thank you for helping!

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: *Is there a general way to solve this sort of questions?* Not really. There are many too many different cases to give you a general approach.

Comment: A general answer to this will be to conditional on one of the variables $(X, Y)$ and use law of total probability. Another similar approach is to find the join pdf of $(X, Y)$, create a dummy variable (say $W$)  to form a one-to-one bivariate transformation, find the joint pdf of $(Z, W)$ using Jacobian method, then integrate out the dummy variable $W$ to form the marginal pdf of $Z$.